# Repeating an algorithm as many times as the user requires (PYTHON 3.3.2 GUI)

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, repeat

I'm trying to repeat this algorithm and use the values in my code, please help!!!

import random

```
def dice_roll(number):
    if number == 12:
        number = random.randint(1,12)
        print(number)
        return(number)
    elif number == 6:
         number = random.randint(1,12)
         print(number)
         return(number)
    else:
        number == 4
        number = random.randint(1,12)
        print(number)
        return(number)
```

dice_roll(int(input("Which dice would you like to roll? --> ")))

Comment: What do you mean by repeat? Like running a Loop until user decides to exit?

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to do this is a `while True` loop, which you `break` when the user quits, e.g.:

```
while True:
    user_input = int(input("Which die would you like to roll (0 to quit)? "))
    if user_input in (4, 6, 12):
        dice_roll(user_input)
    elif user_input:
        print("Not an acceptable die.")
    else:
        break
```

Note that your `dice_roll` function currently always rolls a 12-sided die, and could be simplified:

```
def dice_roll(sides):
    number = random.randint(1, sides)
    print(number)
    return number
```

(this also removes the limit to 4, 6 and 12 only, so you may want to revise the input loop accordingly).

Answer (score 0):

Is it something like this?

```
import random

def dice_roll(number):
    if number == 12:
        number = random.randint(1,12)
        print(number)
        return(number)
    elif number == 6:
        number = random.randint(1,12)
        print(number)
        return(number)
    else:
        number == 4
        number = random.randint(1,12)
        print(number)
        return(number)

while True:
   dice_roll(int(input("Which dice would you like to roll? --> ")))
   doRepeat=input('Go again?')
   if doRepeat == 'no':
      break
```

Edit:

```
 raw_input() was renamed to input().
```

You can use "input()" in 3.x, like older versions, this:

```
doRepeat=eval(input('Go again?'))
```

Comment: You are mixing `input` and `raw_input` (which doesn't exist in Python 3.x).